How to pass the middleware locale to the request when the call is made via an api?
I'm using next 14.2.11 and next-intl 3.22.0 in my project and it's working fine, however, when trying to translate the API responses.
I am receiving the request without a location in the middleware but I want to pass the location that comes in the headers directly from the middleware to the request.ts file, only when it is an api call but I am not having success.
Below I will leave the code I have in middleware.ts and request.ts.
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware'
import { routing } from './i18n/routing'

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware(routing)

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const { pathname } = request.nextUrl

    if (pathname.startsWith('/api') || pathname.startsWith('/_next/') || pathname === '/favicon.jpg' || pathname.startsWith('/images/')) {
        return NextResponse.next()
    }

    const hasLocale = /^\/(en-US|pt-BR)(\/|$)/.test(pathname)

    if (!hasLocale) {
        const acceptLanguage = request.headers.get('accept-language') || 'en-US'
        const userLang = acceptLanguage.split(',')[0].toLowerCase()
        const locale = userLang.startsWith('pt') ? 'pt-BR' : routing.defaultLocale

        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${locale}${pathname}`, request.url))
    }

    return intlMiddleware(request)
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/', '/:locale(en-US|pt-BR)?/:path*']
}

import { getRequestConfig } from 'next-intl/server'
import { routing } from './routing'

export default getRequestConfig(async ({ requestLocale }) => {
    let locale = await requestLocale

    if (!locale || !routing.locales.includes(locale as any)) {
        locale = routing.defaultLocale
    }

    const pagesWithTranslations = ['terms-of-use', 'privacy-policy', 'wedding', 'edit', 'apis']
    let messages = {}

    for (const page of pagesWithTranslations) {
        try {
            const pageMessages = (await import(`../../messages/${locale}/${page}.json`)).default
            messages = { ...messages, ...pageMessages }
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(`Não foi possível carregar as traduções para ${page} no locale ${locale}`)
        }
    }

    return {
        locale,
        messages,
    }
})

